# How do I set transparency correctly to see through image on plane in Cycles?

Tags: image, transparency

When using Cycles, part of my transparent png on a plane shows up as black, and I can't see the blur effect in the background on the planet (for atmosphere). Is there a setting I need to change in order for it to be truly transparent?

[image]

It is transparent in Evee:

[image]

But I want the reflections that I get in Cycles.

You can download a test with the same issue here: https://mega.nz/file/iwgFUYJY#6UxEPZ2BforSP2ljyGb5kWwiZIZDNtjxfaohI7ZiGro

The "Glow Fac" on the Planetary Shader is where the atmospheric glow is coming from, and that's the part that isn't rendering when behind a an image as plane.

[image]

Comment: normally this should work. pls provide blend file, but before, do file - external data - pack resources so we can check out your image too

Comment: @Chris - thanks - Here's the download: https://mega.nz/file/iwgFUYJY#6UxEPZ2BforSP2ljyGb5kWwiZIZDNtjxfaohI7ZiGro

Comment: I thought it had to do with my image on plane being an emitter, but turns out that didn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shader is the reason for this:

If i mute this "facing fresnel", it stops happening.

[image]

This is an compositing example, how you could solve it (i lowered the resolution for quicker render):

[image]

Comment: interesting. But muting that removes the "atmosphere" glow effect as well right? So might just be the method used to create the atmosphere effect won't work with a transparent image plane?

Comment: yes, both are right. One way to avoid/solve this problem would be to use compositing and first render the world, and then above that your transparent image

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help!

Comment: you are welcome